# cumulative layout shift (CLS) in html

Tags: pagespeed, cumulative-layout-shift

I am getting CLS ON this piece of HTML can anyone tell the reason for why iam getting a layout shift. iam trying hard to get the CLS below 0.1 but failed to do so .. i guess bootstrap classes may causing the issue but how can i fix it

```html
<section class="page-banner Games" style="height:400px;">
  <div class="new-banner-collection-page" style="padding-bottom:1rem;">
    <div class="row" style="height:100%">
      <div class="col-md-7" style="height:100%; float:left">
        <div id="tags-new-banner" class="" style="padding-left: 32px;padding-top:17px;">

            <span class="playabe-breadcrum" max-width="100%">
                <a class="playabe-breadcrum js-track-ga" href="/" data-action="{&quot;to Page&quot;:&quot;/&quot;}" data-category="clicked bread crumb" style="display: inline;">Home</a> &gt;
            </span>

            <span class="playabe-breadcrum" max-width="100%">
                <a class="playabe-breadcrum js-track-ga" href="/search_contents/preview/games" data-action="{&quot;to Page&quot;:&quot;/search_contents/preview/games&quot;}" data-category="clicked bread crumb" style="display: inline;">Games</a> &gt;
            </span>

            <span class="playabe-breadcrum" max-width="100%">
                <a class="playabe-breadcrum js-track-ga" href="/search_contents/preview/math-games" data-action="{&quot;to Page&quot;:&quot;/search_contents/preview/math-games&quot;}" data-category="clicked bread crumb" style="display: inline;">Math Games</a> &gt;
            </span>
            <span class="playabe-breadcrum">Counting Games</span>
        </div>

        <div class="title-new-collection-page" style="">
          <h1 style="font-weight:700;">
            Counting Games for Kids
          </h1>
        </div>
             <p class="less-banner-content">
              <span>The first step to embracing math is learning to count. Children learn to identify, group and classify objects by counting. SplashLearn’s cool online counting games provide respite from the monotony of practice worksheets through colorful virtual manipulatives. Children develop a bond </span>
              <span id="js-read-more-banner-btn" onclick="readMoreFunc()" style="color:blue;">... Read more</span>
              <span id="js-read-more-banner-content" style="display:none">with numbers that will see them through advanced math in the upcoming years.</span>
             </p>
        <div class="signup-ctas-new-banner">


            <a class="new-banner-signup-link-parent" href="/parents/register#!/parent/creation">
                <button class="new-banner-signup-btn-parent">Parents, Sign Up for Free</button>
            </a>

            <a class="new-banner-signup-link-teacher" href="/teachers/register">
                <button class="new-banner-signup-btn-teacher">Teachers, Use for Free</button>
            </a>


        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="new-banner-images col-md-5" style="float:right">
            <img alt="Imge" class="" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%;height: 100%;object-fit: contain;" src="http://localhost:8300/cms_assets/images/Common-page.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</section>
```